# Open-Meteo latitude and longitude auto fill in possible?

Tags: python

I am using Open-Meteo as the weather API in my program. I have a database with latitude and longitude of specific countries. I want the code to put the latitude and longitude into the URL and then display the temperature for that country.

I have tried:

```
url = ("https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=latitude&longitude=longitude&hourly=temperature_2m&daily=temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min&timezone=auto&forecast_days=16")
    
response = requests.get(url)
response_json = response.json()
latitude = self.get_latitude()
longitude = self.get_longitude()
```

Comment: Honestly, what you are looking for is a simple GET request. Perhaps you can look into some good material online to understand that. For your reference, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/

Comment: The code that you have tried doesn't make any sense. The solution you are looking for is really simple. Just try to understand the basics of REST API and you can code it easily. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work

#### Save as `get-weather.py` file name

```py
import requests
import json
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

city='paris' # replace any city of country
result_city = requests.get(url='https://geocoding-api.open-meteo.com/v1/search?name=' + city)
location = result_city.json()

longitude=str(location['results'][0]['longitude'])
latitude=str(location['results'][0]['latitude'])

#print('city: ' + city)
#print('longitude: ' + str(longitude))
#print('latitude: ' + str(latitude))

result_weather = requests.get(url='https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude + '&hourly=temperature_2m&daily=temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min&timezone=auto&forecast_days=16')
data = result_weather.json()

times = data['hourly']['time']
dates = pd.to_datetime(times, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

values = data['hourly']['temperature_2m']

#print(dates.to_list())
#print(values)
#print(len(data['hourly']['time']))

plt.plot(dates.to_list(), values)
plt.title(city + " temperature ")
plt.xlabel("hourly")
plt.ylabel("temperature")
plt.show()
```

#### Run it

```
$ python get-weather.py
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Close to what I want but i would like the websites graph to be displayed instead of the data being displayed in the python shell.

Comment: @Toothywhisperer93, OK, I changed it with chart output instead of JSON data. 
Can you accept my answer?

Comment: You are welcome! I am happy to to hear you got it.